# alternative of greater than and less than laravel?

Tags: laravel

I am trying to select 4 different plan groups based on minimum and maximum amount. Expected result is:

1. Plans with `min_amount=1000` and `max_amo=1000`.
2. Plans with `min_amount=1000` and `max_amo=10000`.
3. Plans with `min_amount=110000` and `max_amo=35000`.
4. Plans with `min_amount=100000` and `max_amo=150000`.

My try looks like this:

```
$depositp = Package::where('min_amount','>=',"2000")
->where('max_amo','<=',"2000")
->first();
```

This code is not return expected plan #2, but it selects plan #1 because it meeting both conditions. what i should do?

Comment: Your example is passing the same value. Are you sure the example is correct?

Comment: yes becasue amount of user will be fixed . e,g 2000, now 2000 should be go with plan with has minimum amount greater or eqaul to has also the maximum amount of plan  should not be higher than users input amount that is 2000

Comment: not working errror

Comment: if you change the > to < and vice-versa it should work, but the problem is that you can have the case that multiple plans meet your condition. @waqar
because in my opinion your query should return no plan because none meets the where clauses at the moment

Comment: Under normal circumstances `where('min_amount','>=', '2000')` should not match plan 1 at all since it has a min_amount that's less than 2000 . Do a `dd(Package::where('min_amount','>=',"2000")->where('max_amo','<=',"2000")->toSQL())` and try the generated query directly in MySQL to see if it works as you'd expect there